# Remove last paragraph mark on header with vba

Tags: vba, ms-word, header

I want to remove the last line on the header. I currently have 2 lines in the header: the first one I copy-paste and the second one which was there before the copy-paste (the starting point for the copy-paste).

I tried something like that:

```
`Selection.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1`

`Documents.Open (strFilename)
Selection.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Copy
ThisDocument.Activate
Selection.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Paste
Documents(strFilename).Close (0)`
```

Expect to have only one line, the one I copy-paste from another document
Only one line to gain a bit of space with the header.

OK, here is one picture to understand better my question:

[image: Header with or without extra paragraph mark]
Hope that help!

Comment: The question isn't clear...Maybe if you make screen shots of what you want and what you're actually getting? Remember you can use the [edit] link below the question to add/change information.

Comment: I edit my question with a picture, but macropod understood my question and everything is working as I wanted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the document with the header you want to replicate is active and the macro is in that document:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim DocSrc As Document, DocTgt As Document
Set DocSrc = ActiveDocument
Set DocTgt = ActiveWindow.Next.Document
With DocTgt.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range
  .FormattedText = DocSrc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.FormattedText
  .Characters.Last.Previous = vbNullString
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well. I just added this line: Selection.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Characters.Last.Previous = vbNullString and everything is working as I wanted.

Comment: @JLuc01 Using selections is very inefficient, and copy/paste is unnecessary. My code demonstrates both principles.

Comment: Ok. But, what is the meaning of the abbreviation Tgt (I suppose Src=Source, Tgt?)? In my code, I open a file and use it content. In your code, I don't see how you do it. Concerning the Selection bit, I agree with you, but I still trying to understand how to do it properly: need more reading about it (so far the code I have seen shows me different way to do it and I am a bit confuse).

Comment: @JLuc01 Well, as indicated by Dim DocSrc As Document, DocTgt As Document, DocSrc & DocTgt refer to documents. The names also give an indication of which is which - source (Src) and target (Tgt). I could have used anything for the names (e.g. QWERTY and ZXCVB), instead. Set DocSrc = ActiveDocument denotes your active document as the source, whilst Set DocTgt = ActiveWindow.Next.Document denotes your other document as the target (or destination, if you prefer). Note, too, that there is no need to waste resources activating the latter.

Comment: I think I manage to do it your way. I get rid off the Selection and Copy/Paste. The code seems cleaner (sorry I can't show you in this comment). Thanks again @macropod.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand well what you mean, but I think that what you are looking for is the following, Try it

```
`Selection.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1`

`Documents.Open (strFilename)
    Dim strText() As String
    Dim MyCell As String

    ThisDocument.Activate
    MyCell = Selection.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Text
    strText = Split(MyCell , vbCrLf)
    Selection.Sections(1).Headers(1).Range.Text=strText(0)
    Documents(strFilename).Close (0)


`
```

Comment: I get an error at 'Value' and I didn't understand well your code. Thank you anyway, see the post below for an answer which work for me.

Comment: try it with .text instead of .value and let me know please if it works, if it works I will explain to you my code